# Trouble with Java vowel counter

Tags: java, for-loop

I am having trouble getting my vowel counter to run in the for loop I created for this cap. Here is my code:

```
//java app that counts vowels using a forloop
import java.util.Scanner;
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner ent=new Scanner(System.in);     
String string1; 
System.out.println("Entered a letter:");
string1 = ent.nextLine();}


public static int numberVowels(String string1){
    int count=0;
    int vowels=0;
    int consonants=0;
    for(int i=0; i<string1.length(); i++){

        char ch=string1.charAt(i);
        if(ch=='a' || ch=='e' ||ch=='i' ||ch=='o'||ch=='u' ){

            vowels++;
            return ch=ch+vowel;
        }else{

            consonants++;
        }
    }

}
```

}

It says that there is no return type but I do have a return type. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

You have a return statement in your `if` (and it looks specious to me), you need one that is guaranteed to be *reachable*; since your method is for counting `vowels` you should stick to that. Finally, since you only test lower case vowels, I would recommend calling `toLowerCase` before your test. Something like,

```
public static int numberVowels(String string1) {
    int vowels = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++) {
        char ch = Character.toLowerCase(string1.charAt(i));
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
            vowels++;
        }
    }
    return vowels;
}
```

**or** using a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
public static int numberVowels(String string1) {
    int vowels = 0;
    for (char ch : string1.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
            vowels++;
        }
    }
    return vowels;
}
```

Comment: Of course, consonants is equal to the length of the String minus the value of vowels

Answer (score -1):

Yes the message is regarding Java syntax try to fix using this:

always Java check that have returned a variable if your method has a return type.

`´`

```
//java app that counts vowels using a forloop
import java.util.Scanner;
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner ent=new Scanner(System.in);     
String string1; 
System.out.println("Entered a letter:");
string1 = ent.nextLine();}


public static int numberVowels(String string1){
    int count=0;
    int vowels=0;
    int consonants=0;
    char tmp='';
    for(int i=0; i<string1.length(); i++){

        char ch=string1.charAt(i);
        if(ch=='a' || ch=='e' ||ch=='i' ||ch=='o'||ch=='u' ){

            vowels++;
            tmp= ch=ch+vowel;
        }else{

            consonants++;
        }
    }
return tmp;
}
```

`

Comment: Now it isn't printing out anything when I want to let the program know  that I printed out a vowel:

 char ch=string1.charAt(i);
        if(ch=='a' || ch=='e' ||ch=='i' ||ch=='o'||ch=='u' ){

            vowels++;
            tmp= ch;
            System.out.println("You printed out a vowel");
        }else{

            consonants++;
        }

Comment: Show I call my method in the main method as well